# Changing effective mass to lower frequency

Tags: mass, frequency

I'm trying to scale a physical object up in size, either double or quadruple. It's a circular acrylic plate, with multiple weights attached around it's edge, to lower the resonant frequency to a specific frequency, 32hz.

The plate is 16” in diameter, the weights around it's edge add up to 1.05 kg. It needs to be scaled to 32” or 64”. It will scale in diameter but not thickness, which will remain 1/8” for all diameters.

If the size is doubled to 32”, along with doubling the weights around the edge to 2.1 kg, will the resonant frequency be lowered to the same frequency as the 16” plate with 1.05 kg weights?

If not, how does this scale? How far off approximately will the resonant frequency be from 32hz?

Same question for scaling to 64” with 4.2 kg weights around the edge.

Comment: Do you mean the resonant frequency of the plate itself, or are the plate and weights on a spring?

Comment: The resonant frequency of the plate itself, no spring.

Comment: Is the plate supported at its center?

Answer (score 1):

The mass would scale in the other direction: as you increase the diameter of the plate, you would have to decrease the mass. This is due to the loss of stiffness as your plate gets larger. To give exact detail may require a little more information about the physical setup, but here are some basics.

Frequency is related to $\sqrt{k/m}$. Given the perceived symmetry of the problem, I will simplify this into a 1D problem. For a beam, the stiffness $k$ is proportional to $1/l^3$. So, doubling the length (radius, diameter) will *reduce* the stiffness by a factor of 8. Therefore, you would need to reduce the mass by the same amount.

To double your diameter to 32", your 1.05 kg would reduce to about 0.13 kg. To double it again to 64" would reduce the effective mass to a mere 16 grams, which is probably less than the material itself.